# Coloring Graphics3D as a Function of Spatial Coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color

I would like to plot a `Graphics3D` object colored based on the value of some spatial function. For example to plot a triangle colored by the function `cf` I might start with:

```
testCorners = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
testTriangle = Triangle[testCorners];
cf [{x_, y_, z_}] = ColorData["NeonColors"][z];
```

I hope that there is a couple of lines, probably involving Graphics3D that will plot this triangle (or other, more complicated surfaces) colored with the function I have specified (or other more complicated functions of x, y, and z).

I can do fun stuff like color vertices and have Mathematica linearly interpolate over the faces.

```
Graphics3D[
 Append[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "GraphicsComplex"], 
  VertexColors -> ColorData["NeonColors"] /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20]]]
```

[image: A dodecahedron with its vertices colored]

It may be possible to use a similar method by transforming the surface into a `GraphicsComplex` object and then setting `VertexTextureCoordinates` appropriately and supplying a `Texture` to `Graphics3D`, but that seems quite complicated...

Answer (score 1):

```
gc = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "GraphicsComplex"];
minmax = MinMax @ N @ gc[[1, All, -1]]

Graphics3D[Append[gc, 
  VertexColors -> (ColorData[{"NeonColors", minmax}] /@ gc[[1, All, -1]])]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use your `cf` with rescaled arguments:

```
Graphics3D[Append[gc, 
   VertexColors -> (cf /@ Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose[First @ N @ gc]])]
```

> same picture

**Update:** *"but suppose I had a color function which was radially symmetric like Norm. The dodecahedron would be uniformly colored, even though the centers of each face should have a lower value."*

```
texture = RadialGradientImage["NeonColors"];

Graphics3D[Normal[gc] /. Polygon[x_] :>
  {Texture @ texture,
   Polygon[x, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Rescale[CirclePoints @ Length @ x]]}]
```

[image]

***Further examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
polyhedra = RandomSample[PolyhedronData["Archimedean"], 12];

Graphics3D[Normal[PolyhedronData[#, "GraphicsComplex"]] /. 
     Polygon[x_] :> {Texture @ texture, 
       Polygon[x, 
        VertexTextureCoordinates -> Rescale[CirclePoints @ Length @ x]]}, 
    Lighting -> "Neutral"] & /@  polyhedra // Multicolumn[#, 4] &
```

[image]

Comment: This is useful but suppose I had a color function which was radially symmetric like `Norm`. The dodecahedron would be uniformly colored, even though the centers of each face should have a lower value.

Comment: @alessandro, please see the update.

Comment: That looks spectacular, let me play with it for a second and I'll get back to you.

Comment: This doesn't let me specify an arbitrary function. It just maps the same image on to each face. An texture for each face could be made I suppose though...